# web crawler on dynamically changing website code

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm currently trying to involve myself more with programming and python. For a little project I wanted to build a web crawler for a website. So I read about **scrapy** and **beautifulsoup**.
So far so good..

### Structure of the website

It's a simple website with a *drop down menu* for available options. If I select one of those, the website URL doesn't change. And only the underlying html code changes.
When selecting a value you get a result table with a few **columns/rows** in the form of:

```
<div id="result">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>...</b></td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
        more follows here...
```

### Task

I wanted to scrape all the date for the resulting tables for *each* of the drop down menu entries..
So far I managed to just extract the drop down menu values.

### Question

How do i actively select the values in the drop down menu so the websites html code changes and displays the wanted table I want to scrape the data from? 
After reading the docs for scrapy and beautifulsoup I still don't understand that part.

### Current Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3

BASE_URL = "http://routerpasswords.com/"

def get_router_types(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
    print("option values: \n")
    option_values = soup.find_all("option")
    print(option_values)
    print(" \n")
    print("router types: \n")
    router_types = [option.get('value') for option in soup.find_all('option')]
    print(router_types)
    return router_types

'''
Stuck here!
...

def get_passwords():
    router_types = get_router_types(BASE_URL)
    passwords = []
    for types in router_types:
        #print(types)

def main():
    get_router_types(BASE_URL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You need something like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). See [Getting Started](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time you click an button, you are posting data to server, you can find the post data in chrome development tools(F12):
[image]

you can mimic this post using `requests`:

```
In [27]: data = {'findpass':'1',
    ...: 'router':'Belkin',
    ...: 'findpassword':'Find Password'}

In [28]: r = requests.post('http://routerpasswords.com/', data=data)
```

Comment: thanks this comment helped me a lot. Didn't knew that! Thank you :)

Comment: @ricksanchez welcome to SO, if you find my answer is helpful, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

first i get all router_names in a list,

then do for every router a new request with correct post params (def: get_passwords_via_name)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

BASE_URL = "http://routerpasswords.com/"


def get_router_types(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
    print("option values: \n")
    option_values = soup.find_all("option")
    print(option_values)
    print(" \n")
    print("router types: \n")
    router_types = [option.get('value') for option in     soup.find_all('option')]
    return router_types, r

def get_passwords_via_name(router_name, rcookie):
    data = {"findpass": "1", "router": router_name, "findpassword":  "Find+Password"}
    print data

    c = requests.post('http://routerpasswords.com/', data=data)
    print c.url

    html_content = c.content
    print c.status_code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
    return soup.find("div", {"id": "result"})

def main():
    rlist, r = get_router_types(BASE_URL)
    for i in rlist:
        print "debug"
        print get_passwords_via_name(i, r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) way:

```
 curl 'http://routerpasswords.com/'   --data 'findpass=1&router=ZyXEL&findpassword=Find+Password'
```